# Visual Studio 2017 Prevent Ignore of Packages folder on pending changes TFVS

Tags: c#, tfs, nuget, visual-studio-2017, nuget-package

Currently Visual Studio 2017 seems to ignore the packages folder by default when reviewing pending changes so I have to manually add them which can be time consuming - The trouble is that I actually want to commit nuget packages into source control via TFVS. I understand that this isn't the 'correct' way of doing things (nugets should be pulled via nuget restore). But unfortunately with the solution I am currently working on packages are committed into source control. Is there a global ignore configuration I can amend to allow package changed to be auto detected?

Thanks.

Comment: It's possible to disable SC integration via config file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuget-config-file#solution-section

Comment: Thanks - But this appears to only work at solution level. It would be great if there is something that works globally.

Comment: There are also global config files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/configuring-nuget-behavior

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve that globally, you can edit the default ignore configuration file "**LocalItemExclusions.config**" to let VS 2017 to detect the packages files automatically.

Please follow below steps to do that:

1,  Open the **LocalItemExclusions.config** file which under below path (You need to make sure open the folder that matches your VS version, VS 2017 should be 7.0) :

```
"C:\Users\{youraccount}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\x.0\Configuration\VersionControl"
```

2, Remove the default ignored files' extension then save the file,`*.dll` for example here:

```
 <Exclusion>*.dll</Exclusion>
```

3, Thus VS 2017 will detect the new added package files automatically, you can check them in **Pending Changes** page (Excluded Changes area )

4, Click the **Detected** link, click **Promote**, then check in the changes.

Comment: @L1ng Have you resolved the issue by above workaround?

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `.tfignore` file to the solution root (on the same level as your packages folder)

.Add a line `!\packages` to this file to explicitly re-include it.

The **pending changes** list in VS will take this file into account. The packages folder should now be listed to be added to source control.